# No update data after timeout in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I have a doubt about the binding in AngularJS. This is an example of my code:

```
.controller("user", function(){
    this.test = 'hi!';
    this.getCourseSeriesProducts = function(){          
        setTimeout(function(){
            alert(this.test);
            this.test = 'bye';
            alert(this.test);
        },3000);
    }
});
```

The question is, in the first alert after the `setTimeout`, the result is undefined, but in theory should have the 'hi!' value. So, when I change the result to alert 'bye', the value on screen doesn't change and still being 'hi!'. What's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful with the usage of the this keyword. In your function
this.getCourseSeriesProducts, the context has changed so *this* doesn't refer to the same context as when *this.test* was first defined.
I suggest putting a few console.log(this) to understand.

Comment: ok, I understand what you mean, but I don't know how could I do it to change this value inside the timeout funcion.

Comment: ok! I got it! Just writting `.bind(this)` at the end of the funcion. Thanks @komo

Answer (score 0):

Please see demo below,
use angular $timeout instead setTimeout and you need to call function to executed it.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

  var test = 'hi!';

  this.getCourseSeriesProducts = function() {

    $timeout(function() {
      alert(test);
      test = 'bye';
      alert(test);
    }, 300);
  }

  this.getCourseSeriesProducts();


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">


  </div>
</div>
```